# ORDER BY column of joined table performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have 2 tables in 1:1 relation (but it possibly could become a 1:N relation in the future) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
   article_id INT,
   inserted DATETIME
) ENGINE InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE article_top (
   article_top_id INT,
   article_id INT,
   until DATETIME
) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

What I need to do is select articles sorted first by `article_top.until DESC` and after by `article.inserted DESC` (so the "top" articles are on the top and the rest is sorted from the newest to the oldest).

I do following query, which is slow (fast when I skip the `article_top.until` in the ORDER BY clause):

```
SELECT * FROM article 
LEFT JOIN article_top
ON article.article_id = article_top.article_id 
ORDER BY article_top.until DESC, article.inserted DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Is there anything I can do for optimize the query beside merging the two tables into single one (losing possibility of 1:N relation)?

I was thinking about adding additional column to the table `article` and using triggers to update it. This way I could add index to the both columns and ordering should be faster.

Is there any other way how to optimize the query?

Thanks

Comment: What indexes do you have now on article_top please?

Comment: I have index on `article_id` and `article_top_id` ... but the query is slow when the `article_top` table is empty, so I am not sure if adding index to `until` would help.

Comment: both columns in the order by should probably be indexed...a missing index on article_top.until could be the cause the poor performance, but have a look at the query plan first.

Comment: I've added the index and the query time didn't change at all. As I said, the table `article_top` is empty at the moment and in the future it will have much less rows than the `article` table.

Comment: @gbn: indexes will not help in this case, as long as the column we want to sort with comes from `LEFT JOIN`ed table

Comment: @zerkms: still useful to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `top_until` column to the `article` table and have its value copied from `article_top` table (manually at insert time or using trigger) and give articles that are not in article_top table zero "top_until" value. Then have a multi-column index on `top_until` and `inserted` columns:

```
INDEX( top_until, inserted )
```

and query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM article 
   ORDER BY top_until DESC, inserted DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

This should give the results instantaneously.

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking of. Maybe it's the best. Only a question: there are more indexed columns in the `article` table which are sometimes used in WHERE clause for filtering purpose. Could this fact (negatively) affect use of the composite index while sorting? Should I add some of the columns into the composite index?

Comment: @PetrPeller If you want MySql to use the index when ordering the columns they must appear in the ORDER BY clause in the same order as they appear in the index, also you should not mix ASC and DESC. You can have additional columns at the end of the index but not the beginning, `INDEX( top_until, inserted, other_column )` will work but `INDEX( other_column, top_until, inserted )` will not.

Comment: I am aware of this, but the mysql documentation states that index is not used when: "The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: @PetrPeller If you put the other columns at the beginning of the index and have them in WHERE clause it will use the index. For example say you have an additional `user_id` column, if you put it at the beginning of the index: `INDEX( user_id, top_until, inserted )` and also have `WHERE user_id = 5` in your queries MySql will use the index both to find the user_id and sort the results.

Comment: @PetrPeller If you imagine the index as a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) you will know when MySql can or can't use the index.

Comment: The problem is it's dependent on user input which columns will be used in the WHERE clause. For example user may or may not require filtering by specific article category.

Comment: @PetrPeller Then you need to have multiple multi-column indexes `INDEX( column1, top_until, inserted ), INDEX( column2, top_until, inserted ), ...`